# Pair all columns from dataframe into a list in R

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

Imagine I have a dataframe with 4 columns (a,b,c,d) in R. I want to code a function which gives the following output in a list of lists:
*(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d), (c,d)*

Obviously I dont want duplicates which would be like (a,b) and (b,a) as they are the same in this case.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  Please remember that SO is not a code writing service.  The community is happy to help you solve problems you encounter in developing your code, but it's much less willing to do your work for you.

Comment: Do you want to content of the columns to be in the lists or only the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `?combn` with a function to be called for each combination of the data.frame's names.

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:4]

combn(names(df1), 2, function(x){
  d <- df1[x]
  names(d) <- x
  d
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: You can just do `combn(df1, 2, simplify = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Roland Yes, of course. Why haven't I seen that :(?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1,
                 b = 2,
                 c = 3,
                 d = 4)
```

You can use this formula to create a list of the column names:

```
df.list <- split(t(combn(names(df), 2)), seq(nrow(t(combn(names(df), 2)))))

> df.list
$`1`
[1] "a" "b"

$`2`
[1] "a" "c"

$`3`
[1] "a" "d"

$`4`
[1] "b" "c"

$`5`
[1] "b" "d"

$`6`
[1] "c" "d"
```

If you rather also show the content of these columns you can follow up with:

```
for (i in 1:length(df.list)) {
  df.list[[i]] <- df[df.list[[i]]]
}

> df.list
$`1`
  a b
1 1 2

$`2`
  a c
1 1 3

$`3`
  a d
1 1 4

$`4`
  b c
1 2 3

$`5`
  b d
1 2 4

$`6`
  c d
1 3 4
```